# How to change block's current time in testrpc

Tags: go-ethereum, testrpc

I created a smart contract, in that i'm assigning now to particular value.

uint raisedtime=now;
EmitNow(raisedtime); //event function.

It return the unix timestamp of vary old date.
How to change or update the timestamps in testrpc.

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12267/now-block-timestamp-not-working-on-testrpc

Comment: I have gone through the thread earlier itself. It was not explained how to update the blocktime of the testrpc. He tried and worked. Mystery remains  there also.